# problems setting 'src' attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my code. I suppose it should get first letter or number from 'src' of a THUMB image and set is as a source for large version (which numbered from 1 to 5). After this it should show large image.

```
$('img.thumb').mouseover(function (){
    $(this).effect('bounce', 500, function(){
        var src = 'images/screens/' + $(this).attr('src').substr(0,1) + '.jpg';
        $('.slideShow img').attr('src' ,src);
        $('.slideShow img').toggle('bounce').css('margin-top','2.5%');
        });
    });
```

The problem is that when I load page (I use Google Chrome) it sets image source as follows - images/screens/i.jpg, for all images, so the big image is not displayed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it would help to have an example of the thumbnail source and what you want for the full size image. `.substr(0,1)` is what is causing the single letter image name.

Comment: figure out the HTML base tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for only the first number or letter, this should do it:

```
$('img.thumb').mouseover(function (){
    $(this).effect('bounce', 500, function(){
        var src = 'images/screens/' + $(this).attr('src').match(/(\/|^)([a-z0-9])[^\/]*$/i)[2] + '.jpg';
        $('.slideShow img').attr('src' ,src);
        $('.slideShow img').toggle('bounce').css('margin-top','2.5%');
    });
});
```

What I did was use a regular expression to find the first number or letter after either the last slash OR the start of the string if there are no slashes. This way your thumbnail source could be "/images/screens/1-thumb.jpg" or "1-thumb.jpg" and you will still get "1" back from the regular expression in both cases.

There are much better ways to do this, because now you are limited to single character file names. You should consider using a pre/postfix for the thumbs and just remove the pre/postfix. In this case you could use this simpler and cleaner line of code:

```
var src = $(this).attr('src').split('-thumb').join('');
```

As long as you don't have any folders or files name with `-thumb` this will support any file name appended with `-thumb`, such as `/images/screens/my-image-thumb.jpg` which becomes `/images/screens/my-image.jpg`

Comment: Here is a full thumbnail tag -img id="3-thumb" class="thumb" src="images/screens/3-thumb.gif". And image name is single number + .jpg

Comment: Sorry. Already figured out my mistake. I should use 'id' attribute instead of source

Comment: that would definitely do it. you could also forget about the id attribute and just use src if you use my split concept above.

Comment: Levi your answer with .split and .join works fine, but can I use it in case I have different image types: for thumbnails I have .gif, but for larger images I have .jpg ???

Comment: no, if you're thumbnails are different file types you will need to also correct the extension on the url for the full size. I would recommend always using the same extension for your thumbnail equivalent to your full size image. OR if your thumbnails are ALWAYS gif, you could do something like `image-name.jpg-thumb.gif` and use `-thumb.gif` as the split argument.